# AngularJS Login Module

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and started implementing login/logout for my assignments.

What i am doing now is-

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams,fromState) {
      var token = SessionService.get('token')
       LoginService.isLoggedIn({token:token}).$promise.then(function(response){
         if(!response.error){
         var isLoggedInOnServer = response.object
         var requireLogin = toState.data.requireLogin
         if(!isLoggedInOnServer && requireLogin){
           console.log("1....")
           event.preventDefault()
           $state.go('user.signin');
         }
         console.log(toState.data.title,['signin','signup','forget'].indexOf(toState.data.title),isLoggedInOnServer,requireLogin)
         if(isLoggedInOnServer && !requireLogin && ['signin','signup','forget'].indexOf(toState.data.title) > -1){
           console.log("2....")
           $state.go('app.dashboard')
         }
       }else{
         console.log("3....")
         event.preventDefault();
         $state.go('user.signin')
       }
      })
```

The problem with this is when i hit a secure page, it first got there and show that page in flicker then return to login page if i am not login.

If i am not login this should immediately redirect me to login page instead of that secure page.

Like Spring-security in spring, can any body tell me robust login mechanism or some logic that i can implement?

Comment: What concerns me about your approach is that your `LoginService.isLoggedIn()` method returns a promise. Is that method making HTTP requests? Ideally, the "isLoggedIn()" method is not asynchronous and does not need to return a promise, it should just know if the user is logged in or not (based on a cookie, JWT, or whatever).

Comment: yes, you are right, i am doing this to check some one is logged in actually.Due to asynchronous nature this is happening. Got the answer, thanks for hint

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a login with redirection too.. this is working fine to me.

when i login, the token is stored on a cookie and a variable to render my menubar.

if my cookie is empty and my render too this redirect to the index.html (my login)

```
var miApp = angular.module('Natura', ['ngRoute', 'ngTable', 'ngCookies'])
    .run(function ($rootScope, $location, $cookies, $window, loginService) {
        $rootScope.render = $cookies.get('render');            
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
            if ($window.location.pathname !== "/NaturaWEB/index.html") {
                if ($rootScope.render !== "true") {
                    $window.location.href = 'index.html#/';
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

with `$window.location.pathname` i can control what url is being trying to access.

sorry if this is a lot crappy.